# Java, simple User profiles

Tags: java

a short question.

I want make a small Java app and want create user-profiles (username,password for a login, nothing more)

I created a class UserProfile but I'm not sure how to collect the users.

I had two options in mind:

a) Create ONE instance of UserProfile which contains a two dimensional List whicht contains username,password and when I add a new User I just add it to the list.

b) Create everytime an instance of Userprofile which contains two private Strings username and password.

Which one is better ?

Comment: You should create a class called `User` with the strings `username` and `password` then make an `ArrayList` of the Users

Comment: You may have **List** of `UserProfile` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first suggestion isn't a UserProfile, it is a collection of user information. What if you decide to add the user's birthday? You'd add and extra list right? What if you decide the birthday is optional? Now you have to add blanks into the list to keep indexing the same.

The obvious fix is to store a list of "something" (hint: UserProfile) instead of list a list of strings.

So: you combine the 2. You have the UserProfile object itself and a list of UserProfile objects. Of couuse unless you have a good reason not to, the list of UserProfiles could just be a standard collection class like `ArrayList` or `Vector`.